# Script not generating email

Tags: php, forms, email, header

I have a simple form script that's supposed to generate an email.  It's been working just fine for about a year, but then I changed my hosting and now the script still redirects to the "thank you" page, but the email isn't generated.  I don't think I've changed anything.  Can y'all look over my script and see if there's anything wrong with it?  Or is it the new hosting's fault?

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  



 header( 'Location: http://amvleague.vitaminh.info/thankyou.html' ) ;

}
die();
?>
```

Comment: Please have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - strip your code down to the bare `mail(..)` call and work from there

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Alrighty, turns out it WAS godaddy's hosting - found this question on SO that saved the day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972812/php-send-mail-form-not-working-with-emails-on-same-domain  Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP mail function you can start by testing this code if it sends to your email. If you need mails with headers you can check on the PHP mail documentation for more example. If you did not receive any mails then you have problems with your hosting.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test and handle if the mail action go well or not:

```
if( mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
// Ok my mail is well send I can redirect
    header( 'Location: http://amvleague.vitaminh.info/thankyou.html' ); 

} else {
// handle error
    print_r(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Alright, I changed this in the PHP code, and now the redirect isn't happening - it just goes to a blank white screen.  Any ideas where I should go from here?